# Naming dataframe passing it as argument in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, function

I want to know how I can build a function where I can pass the name of the dataframe that I will create as argument.

Here I have an example:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

def say_hi(list1, list2):
    lists = zip(list1, list2)
    df = pd.DataFrame(lists, columns=('A', 'B'))
    return df
```

I created a dataframe called df with 3 rows and 2 columns.

My objective is that:

```
def say_hi(list1, list2, DATAFRAME_NAME):
    lists = zip(list1, list2)
    DATAFRAME_NAME = pd.DataFrame(lists, columns=('A', 'B'))
    return DATAFRAME_NAME
```

I created a dataframe called DATAFRAME_NAME with 3 rows and 2 columns. Which I gave its name  passing an argument.

Obviously you cannot apply in this way but I want to know how I could do that.

Comment: you try using the exec function to execute a string containing the assignment statement

Comment: can you develop the answer?

Comment: df is an object (DataFrame) and not the name of it. so you could just do: DATAFRAME = say_hi(list1,list2), in your mainh line of code, and forget your second example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the globals() function instead:

```py
import pandas as pd

def say_hi(list1, list2, df_name):
    lists = zip(list1, list2)
    df = pd.DataFrame(lists, columns=('A', 'B'))
    globals()[df_name] = df
    return df

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]

say_hi(list1, list2, "my_df")
print(my_df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I see the way but the example is wrong, if you execute it appears "name my_df is not defined"

Comment: overlooked on that part, you can instead use globals() function to get a dictionary of the global variables in your program and then assign the dataframe to the key in the dictionary with the name passed as an argument, let me correct that for you